# Opencart, modifying payment module

Tags: opencart

I am using the Barclaycard EPDQ module (by Qphoria) on a clients site which works perfectly but Q isn't answering emails to help with this (paid I might add).

The problem is the default design for the payment page is poor (Barclaycard's end) and we are able via a call back to add our own payment page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="TP" value="">
```

I think I have found the file I need to edit to add in but have no idea where:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @author Qphoria@gmail.com
 * @web http://www.opencartguru.com/
 *
 * @usage
 *      $params = array(
 *          'xxx' => 'value1',
 *          'yyy' => 'value2',
 *          'zzz' => 'value3',
 *      );
 *
 *      $payclass = New PayClass();
 *      $payclass->sendPayment($params);
 */

class barclay_advanced {

    private $_url = 'https://payments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/orderstandard.asp';
    private $_testurl = 'https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp';
    private $_log = '';

    public function __construct($logpath = '') {
        if ($logpath && is_dir($logpath) && is_writable($logpath)) {    $this->_log = $logpath .  basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '.log'; }
    }

    public function buildOutput($params) {

        $url = $this->_url;
        if (isset($params['test'])) {
            unset($params['test']);
            $url = $this->_testurl;
        }

        // Get the key but remove from the form list
        $passphrase = $params['key'];
        unset($params['key']);

        ksort($params);
        $hash = '';
        foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
            $hash .= $k . '=' . $v . trim($passphrase);
        }
        $this->writeLog('HASH STRING: ' . $hash);
        $sha1hash = strtoupper(sha1($hash));
        $params['SHASIGN']  = $sha1hash;

        $data  = 'Redirecting...';
        $data .= '<form action="'.$url.'" id="payform" method="post">';
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'OWNERZIP' && !$value) { continue; } // Skip missing zip
            $data .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';

        }
        $data .= '<input type="submit" value="-->" />';
        $data .= '</form>';
        $data .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
        $data .= 'document.forms["payform"].submit();';
        $data .= '</script>';

        $this->writeLog($data);
        return $data;
    }

    private function writeLog($msg) {
        if ($this->_log) {
            $msg = (str_repeat('-', 70) . "\r\n" . $msg . "\r\n" . str_repeat('-', 70) . "\r\n");
            file_put_contents($this->_log, $msg, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Anyone able to help me out of this jam?

Comment: I don't think that sharing a code from paid extension without the authors permission is a good idea. At least me as author I would be really pissed off.

Answer (score 1):

Just before:

```
$data .= '<input type="submit" value="-->" />';
```

add the line you want to:

```
$data .= '<input type="hidden" name="TP" value="">';
```

alternately find where this function is called: buildOutput($params) and add to the $params
array the
 `'TP' => 'value'`

there are many other alternatives but the best possible approach is to follow the route the developer has allready set, that is with the addition of the parameter in the $params array.